# Disabling Eclipse command handler based on the active workbench page

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development and am trying to disable the command handler of a menu item if the active workbench window is not a `.js` or `.html` file.

I found code to disable it when it is not a text editor as follows:

```xml
<activeWhen>
    <with variable="activeEditorId">
       <equals value="org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor"/>
    </with>
</activeWhen>
```

I want the similar functionality for javascript and html editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using definitions as follows:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
        <definition id="example.definitions.sampleDefinition">
          <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <or>
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                         value="*.html"/>
                 <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                         value="*.js"/>
            </or>
           </adapt>
        </definition>
   </extension>
```

And then we need to use this definition id in the  tag of the corresponding command handler as follows:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
        <with variable="activeEditorInput">
    <reference definitionId="example.definitions.sampleDefinition"/>
  </with>
</enabledWhen>
```

I am using this code. It's working fine.